# Find a continuous function on the reals where $f(x) >0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

We need to find a function $f(x)$ where $f(x) >0 $and $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ where $f$ is continuous for all real numbers.
We have tried $ f(x) = \sqrt{-x}$ however this is not defined for $x>0$ and therefore is only continuous where $x<0$.
Is there even such a function? Because $f$ is positive but decreasing (...increasingly)

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: As you impose conditions about $f'$ and $f''$, mentioning continuity of $f$ is somewhat redundant.

Comment: @Hagen the question stated it? Thought it might be important.

Comment: Those conditions are for all real numbers?

Comment: yes indeed Mr Awesome

Comment: Such a function does not exist:  If the slope is negative and continues to decrease, it is bounded above by a line with negative slope which will eventually be negative.

Comment: Well try drawing a positive function which is decreasing and concave downwards... there isn't any. This is not a very rigorous proof.

Comment: That's why I am asking the question here...

Comment: That's the answer then... No such function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such function does not exist!

If not, there is such $f$ concave, so

$$f(x)\leq f'(0)x +f(0),  \qquad \forall x \in \Bbb R$$

Since $f'(0)\lt0$, so if $x \gt -\dfrac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$, then

$$f(x)\leq f'(0)x +f(0)\lt0$$

Comment: @BCLC: The question states "$f'(x) < 0$".

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$ we have $f'(x)-f'(0)=xf''(\xi)<0$ by the MVT, hence $f'(x)<f'(0)$ for $x>0$. Then for $x>0$ we have $f(x)-f(0)=x\cdot f'(\xi)<xf'(0)$ for some intermediate (but positive)  $\xi$, hence $f(x)< f(0)+xf'(0)$ for $x>0$. Specifically, for $x=-\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}>0$ we obtain $f(x)< 0$.

Comment: So is there such a function?

Comment: Is this a proof by contradiction?